# One of my questions seems to be missing

Tags: discussion, bug, questions

I had a very generic question about Popular beer by country .
Its seems to be missing from my list ?
Why so ?

EDIT :
https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/most-popular-beer-by-country

It seems  deleted why as it has many great answers , I thought it should have been protected by community .

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell from reading this the issue is that the question is far to broad as it is asking for not just popular beer in a country but for every country in the world which will wield far to many answers as this is a very broad question which would raise a flag by stack exchange policy and second it is very opinion based as without people doing a county wide survey of everyone it is impossible to see what the most popular beer is you may well find the best seller but just because it sells well doesn't mean it is most popular over the majority and with this being opinion based thus raising a second flag so with the two flags in mind the site (community) deemed that this question did not fit the question structure and eventually closed of the question

so whilst it might have produced some good answers the were ultimately far too many different answers(Too broad) and not accurate to a fact biases(opinion based) would lead any question to be closed

Hope this helps clear things up a bit

Comment: It emerged for stack community to close this question after 2 years , WOW . Doesn't seem convincing .It could have been modified for best seller by country , if flagged

Comment: @BeerFreezer The question was first closed for being to broad on May 7th 2015 and them was eventually deleted on December 10th 2016 due to no edits being made

Comment: So let me know if I make an edit for more specification now , would the community consider it to repoen , considering it has got many answers linked to it... if i get a chance to edit , ie

Comment: @BeerFreezer I'm not sure as even changing to bestsellers is still asking for a global count and would still be seen as too many answers and it would get stopped by the Auto Mod

Comment: @BeerFreezer you could always make the changes and it will get put for a reopen vote and them we could see what happens there is no harm in trying

Comment: I feel 190+ odd countries , some company could answer in one anwer for all the countries who hold drinks community all over world responsible

Comment: I feel I cannot change or edit anything in existing closed question ... how  can i do it @Jamie

Comment: @BeerFreezer I will un-delete the question for you to make the edits

Comment: Can't edit though , its locked for edit purpose too

Comment: @BeerFreezer I'm not sure what to do then i will get back to you when I know the cause

Answer (score 2):

The question was auto-deleted by Community.  I'm not sure why that happened; while it was closed, the votes, answers, and views should have protected it from deletion.

The question was locked after a failed attempt to migrate the question to meta.

I removed that lock but added a historical lock.  This preserves the question and its answers but sends a clear signal that this is not an example of a good question for our site.  It's way too broad, but with all the answers you can't narrow it down now.  Instead, review the guidelines for asking questions and then ask a new, narrower question for whatever it is you want to know.  Keep in mind that "list all the X" is usually a poor question on Stack Exchange; we're looking for questions that can be answered in a single answer, rather than questions that call for 30+ answers each with a piece of the full answer.